When did 'Sprog' became a word for meaning a child?
My son was born in 1978. I started calling him spriggle sproggle then became sprog.
Called my son Sprog from his birth, 1978, I had not heard of word apart from then. A good few years later I started hearing friends refer to their kids as "sprogs". What date did sprog become to denote a small child?

The full (subscription-only) OED says: sprog slang (chiefly British, Australian, New Zealand, and South African). Originally and chiefly Military. A new recruit; a trainee, a novice. Also occasionally: a person of lower rank. Also attributive. Their first citation is 1941 for the "novice" sense, but by 1944 it also had the sense "A baby or young child".

I first heard it in the 1980s when some of my workmates called a young colleague a 'sprog' - I think in the sense of 'child' rather than 'new recruit'.

1943 [UK] (ref. to early 1930s) C.H. Ward-Jackson It’s a Piece of Cake 56: sprog. Any airman who is u/t—-i.e., under training. This common expression had the following origin: At a technical training school in the early 1930’s, a trade test was set in which one of the questions was, ‘State a name for a toothed wheel.’ One poor wretch answered ‘Sprog,’ confusing a sprocket and a cog. Subsequently airmen undergoing the course came to be known by that word, since when its use has spread wherever R.A.F. personnel are stationed.]. https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/dd5tb6y
